# Fitting logistic regression with PyMC: ZeroProbability error

Tags: regression, python, pymc

To teach myself PyMC I am trying to define a simple logistic regression. But I get a ZeroProbability error, and does not understand exactly why this happens or how to avoid it.

Here is my code:

```
import pymc
import numpy as np

x = np.array([85, 95, 70, 65, 70, 90, 75, 85, 80, 85])
y = np.array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.])

w0 = pymc.Normal('w0', 0, 0.000001)    # uninformative prior (any real number)
w1 = pymc.Normal('w1', 0, 0.000001)    # uninformative prior (any real number)

@pymc.deterministic
def logistic(w0=w0, w1=w1, x=x):
    return 1.0 / (1. + np.exp(-(w0 + w1 * x)))

observed = pymc.Bernoulli('observed', logistic, value=y, observed=True)
```

And here is the trace back with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-43ed68985dd1>", line 24, in <module>
    observed = pymc.Bernoulli('observed', logistic, value=y, observed=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/distributions.py", line 318, in __init__
    **arg_dict_out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 772, in __init__
    if not isinstance(self.logp, float):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 929, in get_logp
    raise ZeroProbability(self.errmsg)
ZeroProbability: Stochastic observed's value is outside its support,
 or it forbids its parents' current values.
```

I suspect `np.exp` to be causing the trouble, since it returns `inf` when the linear equation becomes too high.
I know there are other ways to define a logistic regression using PyMC ([her is one](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/8329ec1b9f861469f896)), but I am interested in knowing why this approach does not work, and how I can define the regression using the `Bernoulli` object instead of using `bernoulli_like`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a your normal stochastastic with `pymc.Normal('w0', 0, 0.000001)`, PyMC2 initializes the value with a random draw from the prior distribution.  Since your prior is so diffuse, this can be a value which is so unlikely that the posterior is effectively zero.  To fix, just request a reasonable initial value for your `Normal`:

```
w0 = pymc.Normal('w0', 0, 0.000001, value=0)
w1 = pymc.Normal('w1', 0, 0.000001, value=0)
```

Here is [a notebook with a few more details](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/02c3dbee7804620c52c2).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put some sort of bound on the probability returned by the logistic function.

Maybe something like

```
@pymc.deterministic
def logistic(w0=w0, w1=w1, x=x):
    tol = 1e-9
    res = 1.0 / (1. + np.exp(-(w0 + w1 * x)))
    return np.maximum(np.minimum(res, 1 - tol), tol)
```

I think you forgot the negative inside the exp() function, too.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the missing negative sign. Your solution solves the same problem as Abrahams solution, but I think the solution proposed by Abraham is preferable for the two reasons: 1) It is shorter. 2) The code will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

@hahdawg's answer is good, but here's something else to consider.

For your uninformative priors on `w0` and `w1` I would first do an eyeball fit and then use uniforms with limits.
Obviously your `w1` is going to be around 1/15 = .07, so a range like .04 to 1.2 might do it.
`w0` is going to be in the range of -80/15 = -5.3, so something like -7 to -3 could do it.

I'm just saying this because `exp` can easily go bananas, so you have to be careful what you feed it.
If your inverse logit function comes out with a value too close to 0 or 1, logistic regression is guaranteed to break.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are you using a `thin` argument in your call to `sample`? There was a bug related to that, and it may be the culprit here.

Besides, thinning is not worthwhile in any case.

Comment: I get the error already when defining the `observed` variable. Not when I sample. So the `thin` argument has nothing to do with this error.